# iPhone recording synchronization protocol

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, synchronization, gamekit

I'm trying to make a simple thing. I want to make 2 different iphone starts to play a video in the exact same moment (the two video has to be synchronized). The two iphones communicate using GameKit and the bluetooth, and they send/receive messages through the bluetooth with a delay that can vary from 90 ms up to 500ms.
I try to make them start at the same time(date and hour), but the time of the devices may be unsynchronized. Anyone knows a good approach/algorithm to make the two devices start a task at the same time with the less delay possible?
There're some algorithms that multiplayer videogames, that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use an existing protocol for synchronization. Look at [NTP](http://www.ntp.org/) for instance.

Comment: I do not want to use the internet to contact time server. Maybe I can try a master/slave approach with the 2 devices

Comment: @Pablosproject I believe Thomash is referring the NTP ideas more than the actual intended use of the protocol. After all NTP is invented to solve similar problem. In that case sync time "with the less delay possible". I guess you could change some implementation or if it is too much trouble at least use the NTP ideas.